# Is it safe to remove manually installed Python 2.7 from Yosemite?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I don't code but needed to use Python just for one simple task. That task specifically required a Python 2.x version. I've downloaded it from https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-279/ and installed. Later, I wanted to remove Python, but learned that OSX has also Python 2.x preinstalled and removing it is dangerous. Is removing the one I've installed (i.e Python 2.7 package in my Applications folder) also dangerous? If not, why Finder asks me to enter my password to move those files to trash, which often required to make changes on system files?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to remove it?

Comment: *You* might not use Python, but the OS might.  Or a third-party app developer using Python as their language of choice.

Comment: if the new installation `replaces` the old one, then it  is okey, since both are 2.7.x releases, but if you remove the systeme-installed on, you can get problems with software dependecies! those dependecies must always see the python 2.7 executable

Comment: There is no problem removing a second installation just don't screw with the system python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the second Python you installed from python.org should be fine: follow the instructions at: https://docs.python.org/2.7/using/mac.html?highlight=uninstall
This Python puts itself in `/Library/Frameworks/` and symlinks in `/usr/local/bin/`. You need admin privileges to remove things from these directories which is why it's asking for your password.

The system installation of Python is in `/System/Library/Frameworks/` and `/usr/bin/python`. Don't mess with it because the OS needs it.

Having said that, unless you're *really* pressed for space, just leave things as they are and enjoy your life.

Answer (score 0):

MAC OS X 10.9 (at least) and above already had python 2.7 installed, so you don't have to manually install one. Installing python and similar packages are not like what you did with your applications. So, if you are not familiar with UNIX or XNU concepts, don't remove it. It will not just remove some binaries, but also lots of library files. Asking password is because removing some library files would need higher privillege, and usually you don't have with normal account.

In a word, in your case, I suggest keep the python, and don't install new one. v2.7 is all you want.

Comment: the OP has already installed a second interpreter  and is asking about removing it